# Campagnolo Ergopower Chorus 9 inaccurate shifting

Tags: repair, shifter, replacement, campagnolo

My Chorus 9 Speed Ergo-power (~2005) got inaccurate during shifting. The local bike repairman couldn't get the dérailleur to shift properly.

Sometimes the chain don't jump down or up after shifting. Some gears are skipped and the pressure points got weak.

What parts do I need to replace? Is it maybe a better idea to replace the whole Shifters with a available new 9 Speed Ergopower like the Xenon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ergopower shifters have a part called G spring that eventually wears out. The symptoms are inaccurate shifting and less sharp clicks, just as you are experiencing. The part is still available, not expensive and relatively easy to change.

I would not replace the shifters with Xenon, as it is generally much lower quality and doesn't allow downshifting multiple cogs at a time like other 2000s Ergopowers.

Comment: Are there other parts which I should replace too?

Comment: Cables and maybe cable housings. New cables shift better and reinstalling old ones after removing levers for disassembly is next to impossible anyway. The click disc can be replaced too, but in my experience it does't wear out nearly as fast as G-springs.

Comment: I replaced the G Spring and the G Spring carrier. Now the shifting has sharp clicks. But it is shifting still inaccurate.

Comment: The next things to do are readjusting the derailleur including B-tension, switching to new cassette and chain, and replacing the cables and cable housings.

Comment: Everything is new except the ergopower and derailleur.

Comment: Hmm, then there's not much left. Jockey wheels in the derailleur? The Ergopower is really simple, I don't think there are other sources of inaccuracy than the springs and ratchet.

Comment: I uploaded some images in this question. Maybe this shows where the problem is.

http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32614/campagnolo-ergopower-inaccurate-shifting-on-high-and-low-cogs?noredirect=1#comment63192_32614

Comment: Good pictures. Like Grame already answered, it's the cable routing. I've been using a similar setup but wrapped outside to match Campagnolo shifter to Shimano derailleur :)