# Campagnolo Ergopower inaccurate shifting on high and low cogs

Tags: repair, shifter, derailleur-rear, campagnolo

I replaced the G-Spring and G-Spring carrier on my 9 speed Chorus Ergopower.
Now it is shifting better and the clicks are sharper, but I can't adjust the derailleur to shift good on all gears good.

[image]

On the blue cogs the chain grinds and jumps on the bigger cogs. On the red cogs the chain needs extra shifting force after the click to jump on the bigger cog.

If I make the tension of the cable higher or lower the chain will not work with the bigger or smaller cogs at the same time.

Any idea what part could be worn out and should be replaced? I think the Ergopower shifter are causing this.

The derailleur hanger seems to be straight. Changing the position with the screw on the derailleur couldn't fix the bad shifting.

[image][image][image]
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Is the cable new?

Comment: The cabel is 2  months/700km old.

Comment: Are you sure the derailleur hanger is straight, and the indexing adjustment has been done properly?

Comment: I added some images, please take a look. I can't tell for sure if the hanger is straight or not. I would say it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have the cable incorrectly routed under the pinch bolt / washer.

You need to route the cable down the same "side" of the pinch bolt, but the washer needs to turn 90 degrees clockwise, so that one "claw" sits in the hole in the derailleur body, one "claw" sits outside the derailleur body next to the free end of the cable and the cable itself should be trapped, in a straight line, under the small extended flange on the washer that has a groove cut in it, for that purpose.

You might need to use a new cable as the way you have it clamped, it's forced a "kink" into it which will probably not straighten out fully and so will always affect the cable tension, slightly, so giving you inaccurate shifting.

Comment: It seems like the proper routing of the cable has fixed my issue. The shifting is now more accurate. I will make a few km with the bike and report/accept your answer.

Comment: Wow! Nice catch Graeme.I was guilty of the same mis routing of the cable. All is well now. Thamks!